# AEM 6: xtype tabpanel unable to change the dimension

Tags: extjs, aem

Is it even possible to change the dimension of a tabpanel. I tried height and width but it's not working. Any pointers.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog"
    height="{Long}600"
    title="Tiles"
    width="{Long}850"
    xtype="tabpanel">
    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">

    </items>
</jcr:root>
```

Thanks

Comment: share a fiddle?? or example??

Comment: I haven't seen an examples of using {Long} in front of the height/width, even after looking at the documentation [link] (http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/ref/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.Ext.TabPanel)  Maybe try removing the {Long} part and see if the height/width works?

Comment: Did you solve this? i have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Change the xtype on cq:Dialog to "dialog", and move the tabpanel 2 levels down, i.e.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog"
    height="650"
    title="Tiles"
    width="850"
    xtype="dialog">
    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        <tabpanel
            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
            xtype="tabpanel">
            <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
            ...
            </items>
        </tabpanel>
    </items>
</jcr:root>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the following structure and it works perfectly:

```
 - cq:Dialog
      - cq:WidgetCollection
           - cq:TabPanel
                - cq:WidgetCollection
                    - cq:Widget
                    - cq:Widget
                    ...
```

as real life example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
              jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog"
              title="Filter Component"
              height="{Long}500"
              width="{Long}550"
              xtype="dialog">
        <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
            <tabs jcr:primaryType="cq:TabPanel">
                <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                    <tab1 jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                          ... more attributes
                          />
                    <tab2 jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                          ... more attributes
                          />
                </items>
            </tabs>
        </items>
    </jcr:root>
```

**NOTE:** Both `width` and `height` attributes must be configured explicitly in the `cq:Dialog` node